# app.set('port' , process.env.port || 3000) typeerror object #<object> has no method 'set' at object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express 4.2.0 and node.js 0.10.12.

The weird thing is that I created a project in `C\program files\node\nodetest` and when I did `npm start` I got no errors.

Now I created a project in `C\program files\node\secondtest` and when I do `npm start` I get 
`app.set('port' , process.env.port 3000) typeerror object #<object> has no method 'set' at object.<anonymous>` and its pointing in `C\program files\node\secondtest\bin\www:5:5`

Truth is , I dont know how to deal with this error, because I dont get what it means. Is it because both my projects listen on `port 3000`?

I just started `secondtest` , I installed succesfully the dependencies with `npm install` and added this in `app.js`

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express app started');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome!');
});
```

Thanks

EDIT

If I leave the default code in `app.js` and `www` I get no errors. If I replace the default code of `app.js` with mine, and I remove the

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

part from `www`, then I get no errors.

Because I guess `app.set`  and `app.get` are depricated in `express 4.2.0`? Or because when I set an http server in my `app.js` code, conflicts the default `www` code? Either one of these, or I am really confused.

EDIT 2
This is the default code of the `www`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('secondtest');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated answer according to the updated question**.

Since you're calling `www` and its code needs to set the port and listen to it, your `secondtest` code should not listen to the port. Instead it **should** export the Express `app` as follows:

```
// ...
module.exports = app;
```

The `www` will do the listening part.

Otherwise, the `secondtest` tries to start listening on a port while not exporting the Express `app`, and `www` tries to listen again on a variable `app` which is not an Express app, thus the error `object #<object> has no method 'set'`.

When you do `var app = require('../app');` in another script, it is important so that this `../app` script actually exports the Express `app`.

**Old answer**.

Do `node app.js` instead of using `npm` command.

Second, make sure the same port is not used by both processes at the same time. You can't listen to the same port unless you're in [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) mode.

Considering the following is the content of both `firsttest` and `secondtest`:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.port || 3000, function() {
    console.log('Express app started');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome!');
});
```

Do the following to start both apps:

Terminal 1: (the first app will default to port `3000`).

```
$ node firsttest/app.js
```

Terminal 1:

```
$ export PORT=3001
$ node secondtest/app.js
```

Comment: Thanks. But please check the edit in my question if you like. Thanks

Comment: Without the code of `www`, it's difficult to judge what's wrong with it or what conflict arises. Update your question, and I can check it again.

Comment: I just upadated. Thanks